# Is possible to load log4j2 config from config server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, log4j2

Is possible to load log4j2 config.yml from config server or reaload spring boot logging configuration allways from the config server?
Or get the config from a git?
For example:

```
logging:
  config: http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/admin123/config-repository/src/master/log4j2.yml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must read the file in raw mode to get the configuration from gogs.
So, your url with be something like this:

http://xxx.xx.xx.75:3000/admin123/config-repository/raw/master/log4j2.xml

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by specifying the destination URL with system property `log4j.configurationFile`. This accepts any wellformed URL.

Comment: But, in my example is a Git repository running in a docker googs container, and if a just use the URL like in the examle I get an error: [Fatal Error] log4j2.xml:37:4: El tipo de elemento "link" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "</link>".

Comment: If I put: http://xxx.xxx.xx.75:3000/admin123/config-repository/raw/master/log4j2.xml are logged just some lines of logging ending with: Could not find key 'logging.config' in any property source. Returning [null]

Comment: @RemkoPopma do u have a sample code that loads the log4j2.xml from config file based on the environment. I am using cicd and i wanna load log4j2.xml file for different environment. I am using pivotal cloud foundry.